# Convert images(Bitmap) to a popular video format on Android

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-capture

I am creating an **Android App** for recording the **Android screen** (on a rooted phone) like the way Fraps/Camptasia does on a PC. Now i have a set of Bitmap images which i want to convert to a video format.
I have looked over the internet for ways to do so. there is a way to use FFMPEG, which involves building it for the android phone, but it is too complicated with JNI code,etc. Moreover I even tried looking up the mpeg standards so that i can make an encoder myself. But I can't find any information anywhere.
How do I go about doing this?

Digvijay

Comment: Why are you compressing to png? You should have a series of bitmap images in memory, assuming you are storing the result of getDrawingCache.

Comment: Woops, they are indeed bitmap. My mistake. Lemme edit.

Comment: http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/javadoc/org/monte/media/quicktime/QuickTimeWriter.html This looks like it does what you want, while remaining the easiest to use. I'd give it a try. http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2010/10/writing-quicktime-movies-in-pure-java/